# How to get links to open in the native browser in iOS Meteor apps?

Tags: ios, meteor, safari

How do I prevent external links from opening in the in-app browser in apps built with Meteor for iOS? I want them to open in Safari instead.

Comment: Try adding target="_blank" to anchor

Comment: If only it was that easy. I was assuming that was the way to do it, but it isn't. Links with target='_blank' open within the app.

Comment: any solutions yet? in my case links won't open at all.

Comment: Nope. I'm surprised this is such a difficult to resolve issue. Wouldn't this be the most obvious thing to get right, first?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to download and install an apache cordova plugin to add this functionality into your meteor ios app.

Simply run this command into your terminal

```
meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/tarball/ba7cbe58d5812b51c3ece1
```

(here is a [ref](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) to the tarball/ba7cbe58d5812b51c3ece1) (use the latest commit  to master branch)

Then simply add this into your meteor template to launch the system default browser app with the external link:

```
<a href="" onclick="window.open('http://www.example-url.com', '_system');">
Hope this helps!
</a>
```

Run:
meteor run ios-device

(select your trusty simulator and test her out)

Comment: Thanks. I don't know enough about this to resolve the issue I get when running the suggested command: Must declare exact version of dependency: cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/tarball/ba7cbe58d5812b51c3ece1

Answer (score 2):

Nick's answer to use the [inappbrowser Cordova plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/) is sound, but with the error you're seeing, make sure you're providing a full commit hash URL for the `meteor` tool/build to resolve. At the time of this writing, the correct Terminal command to use the latest commit is:

`meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/tarball/bc9036d90a1f3f2220b5fc29b77cf2405e7fd781`

The remaining steps are the same; use the `_system` target in your project's code for the link:

```
<a href="" onclick="window.open('http://external.url', '_system')">Open</a>
```

Then kick off a `meteor build` for your desired mobile platform and Cordova should apply the plugin without issue. Verified these steps work on Meteor 1.2.1.

Comment: Thanks. I found roughly the same solution, here: https://forums.meteor.com/t/open-links-outside-the-app/4538/10